# BlurView below a button with fading edges

Tags: ios, swift, view, core-graphics, blur

I created a button on top of my mapView. 
In order to make that Button more visible I added a blur view below that button.
I don't like the sharp edges of my blur view.
How do I make the blur fade out slowly transitioning into the mapView?

**EDIT:** To be more specific. I mean a fading blurred gradient with round corners.

[image]

Comment: Can you put the code you are using to add the button on map.

Comment: I'm using storyboard

Comment: Would you paint a picture to show the button appearance what you want. It's difficult to draw button in code according to your blurred description

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this can help you, first you need subclass your button and add this code in `drawRect` and replace `UIColor.blueColor().CGColor` by `yourColor.CGColor`

```
class UICustomBackgroundButton: UIButton {

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        // Drawing code
        super.draw(rect)
        let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

        let path = CGPath(roundedRect: rect.insetBy(dx: self.frame.size.height/4, dy: self.frame.size.height/4) , cornerWidth: self.frame.size.height/8, cornerHeight: self.frame.size.height/8, transform: nil)

        ctx?.setShadow(offset: CGSize.zero, blur: self.frame.size.height/4, color: UIColor.blue.cgColor);
        ctx?.setFillColor(UIColor.blue.cgColor);

        //if number of cicles is our glow is darker
        for _ in 0..<6
        {
        ctx?.addPath(path);
        ctx?.fillPath();
        }
    }

}
```

I Hope this helps you.

and this is how it look [image]

Comment: I get this error trying to run your code: 
Assertion failed: (corner_height >= 0 && 2 * corner_height <= CGRectGetHeight(rect)), function CGPathCreateWithRoundedRect, file /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/Quartz2D_Sim/Quartz2D-1033.1/CoreGraphics/Paths/CGPath.cc, line 190.

Comment: @mike I had edited my code, this error happens because values are statics, so now my code make adjustments according your button height, I hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `cornerRadius` property? That should remove the sharp edges